# resetting quiz game choices using flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio, reset

I started a quiz game using flutter,

I added a reset button to replay the game.

but previous choices didn't reset, I have a problem resetting the choices to play again.

the choices reset only if I restart (run) the app from scratch.